# how to pass data from one test to another using set/getattribute in testng rest api testing?

Tags: rest, testng

I am having issue where I am able to extract the token from login response

[image]

So when I do `System.out.println(testContext.getAttribute("AUTH_TOKEN"));` it prints token but when I use this token in next method to create user it 
becomes null

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this is because your second method is running before the first one.

Please change it to as below

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods="testStatusCode")
public void createUser1(ITestContext testContext) {
//Test code goes here
}
```

This will ensure that the method `createUser1()` runs only after the method `testStatusCode()` (wherein you are setting the `AUTH_TOKEN` into the `ITestContext` as an attribute)

Comment: Thank you Krishnan Mahadevan for the response it seems working i can see it printing the token..but for some reason its complaining `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2017 18:05:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 47

{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Unable to process JSON"
}`

Comment: @WaheedAhmed If my answer helped you answer your question, please accept it.